# Single certificate to talk to 5 third party boxes

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I have a web application that uses CURL to talk to 5 boxes that are running third party SDKs. All 6 boxes use HTTPS. Is it fine if we have one certificate and specify CURL to use that certificate to talk to the 5 boxes or do I need to have 5 different certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use 2-way SSL, you don't need any certificate to connect to servers. You just need  the root certificate of the CA. If they use commercial CAs, the root certificate is already included in Curl/OpenSSL.

In summary, you probably don't need to do anything to connect to the 5 boxes.